# SQL testing a user defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, ssms

I have the following code. I am trying to test the function by passing in a @Hire_Date Datetime and seeing what value would be returned However I am new to SQL server 2012 and have no idea how I would go about doing this.

Thanks.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getYearsOfService (@Hire_Date Datetime) 
RETURNS int
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @thisYear int
    DECLARE @thisMonth int
    DECLARE @hireYear int
    DECLARE @hireMonth int
    DECLARE @yearlengthOfService int
    DECLARE @monthlengthOfService int

    SET @thisYear = YEAR(getdate())
    SET @thisMonth = MONTH(getdate())
    SET @hireYear = YEAR('@Hire_Date')
    SET @hireMonth = MONTH('@Hire_Date')

    SET @yearlengthOfService = (@thisYear - @hireYear);
    SET @monthlengthOfService = (@thisMonth - @hireMonth);  

    IF (@monthlengthOfService < 0)  
        SET @yearlengthOfService = (@yearlengthOfService - 1);

    RETURN @yearlengthOfService
END;
```

Comment: Did you know that SQLServer includes its own function to find the difference between two dates? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `SELECT`:

```
SELECT dbo.getYearsOfService(GETDATE())
```

or

```
SELECT dbo.getYearsOfService(CAST('2021-01-20' as DATETIME))
```

(Perhaps the hire date of the next president of the U.S.)

If you have a table of dates, you can use the value in the table as well:

```
SELECT dbo.getYearsOfService(datecol)
FROM t;
```

Comment: Hi, 
On trying this I get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @RajanKerai . . . That error would be impossible for the first two queries in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would just query the function like this:

```
SELECT dbo.getYearsOfService ('02/25/2017')
;
```

Or if you want to use the function against a record in a table, you would query it against a value from that row, like this:

```
SELECT dbo.getYearsOfService(<ColumnName>)
FROM <TableName>
WHERE <SomeColumn> = <SomeValue>
;
```

Or if you wanted to return values together with it, you could run it against the whole table (or part of it), like this:

```
SELECT <Column1>, <Column2>, <Column3>, dbo.getYearsOfService(<ColumnName>) AS <WhateverNameYouWant>
FROM <TableName>
WHERE <SomeColumn> = <SomeValue> -- Optional WHERE Clause
;
```

**NOTE:**

Please notice that in the body of your function, you have an error:

```
SET @hireYear = YEAR('@Hire_Date')
SET @hireMonth = MONTH('@Hire_Date')
```

You don't want to pass strings here, but the parameter value.  Do away with the apostrophes and you should get a clean run with no errors.

```
SET @hireYear = YEAR(@Hire_Date)
SET @hireMonth = MONTH(@Hire_Date)
```

Comment: Hi, 
On trying this I get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Probably because your default date format for the DB is different.  Try reversing the date format from Month/Day/Year to Day/Month/Year, so `25/02/2017'.

If you're getting that error when trying to run against the value of a column, then apparently that column is holding a value which isn't properly formatted to be passed to the function.  Can you tell me which value you were trying to pass to the function?

Comment: I was trying with the value ('02/25/2017'), however this function is part of a larger program where I need to check dates in a column for another tables. The dates in that column are formatted as: '2003-06-28 17:11:25.000'.
I tried both functions you wrote - entering a date manually and against a record in a table and get the same error.

Comment: Updating my answer.

Comment: The error wasn't coming from the dates being passed into the function, but from an error in the syntax of the function itself.  Please see the update answer for an explanation.  `YEAR('@HireDate')` was throwing the error, because the string '@HireDate' is not a date (i.e., cannot be converted to a date from which to pull the `YEAR()`, hence the error)